# Problemas al mostrar/enlazar datos de un XML en un XSL con chrome

Tags: xml, xsl, xslt, openxml

Tengo un xml enlazado con un xsl. Mi intención es mostrar los datos del xml desde el Xsl.

Actualmente tengo los dos ficheros en el mismo directoria de mi sistema operativo. Al ejecutar el xsl el navegador me muestra el código escrito en el fichero, pero no el resultado esperado que es el contenido xml.

He probado con chrome y con internet explorer y el resultado es el mismo.

Este seria mi XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ejercicio4.xsl"?>
<vehiculos>
    <vehiculo anho="1996" marca="Land Rover" modelo="Discovery">
        <kilometros>36500</kilometros>
        <color>Negro</color>
        <precio>22100</precio>
    </vehiculo>
    <vehiculo anho="1998" marca="Toyota" modelo="Land Cruiser">
        <kilometros>47851</kilometros>
        <color>Verde</color>
        <precio>38000</precio>
    </vehiculo>
    <vehiculo anho="1997" marca="Land Rover" modelo="Defender 90">
        <kilometros>46000</kilometros>
        <color>Plata</color>
        <precio>32100</precio>
    </vehiculo>
</vehiculos>
```

Y este mi xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/> 
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head><title>Vehiculos Usados</title>
                <h1 style ="background-color: #446600; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 20pt; text-align: center; letter-spacing: 1.0em">Vehiculos Usados</h1>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/"/>   
            </head> 

            <body>
                <div>
                    <table align="center" border="2">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Año</th>
                            <th>Marca</th>
                            <th>Modelo</th>
                            <th>Kilometraje</th>
                            <th>Color</th>
                            <th>Precio</th>
                        </tr>   

                    </table>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template> 


        <xsl:template match="/">
            <html>
            <xsl:for-each orderedlist= "+precio" select="vehiculos/vehiculo">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select=""/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="marca"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="modelo"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="kilometros"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="color"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="precio"/></td>

                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </html>
        </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Soy nueva en el mundo de la programación. ¿Podéis ayudarme?
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías abrir el documento XML en el navegador para que aplicara un XSLT referido en el XML. Sin embargo, en Chrome eso solo funcionará si cargas el XML de un servidor sobre HTTP(S), no funciona con archivos cargados directamente del sistema de archivos.

En tu caso, el XSLT además tiene varios errores, no se permite el atributo orderedlist como el elemento `for-each`, el primer template tiene una recursión indefinida y no tiene sentido tener dos templates con el mismo `match="/"`.

Comment: Muchas gracias Martin, consegui verificar los errores y pude hacer que funcionase.

Answer (score 0):

Pincha con el boton derecho en el **Chrome/Propiedades** añadir comillas doble a la ruta de esta manera `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"` y le añades al final esto `--allow-file-access-from-files`

**Quedaria algo asi.**

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files`